# Java Spring CRUD repository method "deleteById" doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, crud

I just stacked into a problem with my web Spring application. I added a method deleteById which declared in MessageRepo which extended from CRUDRepository. This method works perfect and it redirect to my "main" page, but there are nothing change in my MySQL DB. Hope that anybody can answer me what's wrong with my app. Feel free to answer. Look down below for this method in my controller

```
    @PostMapping("/main/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {

        messageRepo.deleteById(id);

        return "redirect:/main";
    }
```

That's my how my messages look like in view with button for delete anything.

```
                        <#list messages as message>
                        <div class="task-card">
                            <p class="task-card-p">${message.text}</p>
                            <form method="post" action="/main/${message.id}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                                <button type="submit" class="task-card-btn">delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        </#list>
```

That's my messageRepo. There no any methods cause of i extended of crudRepo.

```
public interface MessageRepo extends CRUDRepository<Message, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Share the Message entity and is messageRepo autowired?

Comment: put it on debug mode like this `logging.level.org.springframework=debug ` and check what is the query being generated?

Comment: @dassum ya, messageRepo @autowired and my message entity here: ` @Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String text;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User author;



    public String getAuthorName() {
        return author != null ? author.getUsername() : "<none>";
    }

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, User user) {
        this.author = user;
        this.text = text;
    }`

Comment: @DeepakSingh am i need to add it in my application.properties ? and then run it in debug mode or just run it in basic mode

Comment: no just add this line to your properties file and restart your service, you'll see lots of logs and then you can analyze what log is being generated from your crud

Comment: can you debug into the request mapping (looking at id)? can you check(follow/debug) the id on db? (???)

Comment: and maybe a misunderstanding: is `CRUDRepository` a custom interface? I am aware of (org.springframework.data.repository.)`CrudRepository` (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `@Transactional` annotation on your controller's delete method. You have to import `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` to use this annotation. Also make sure you add getters and setters in your Message class.
This solution will do the work for you but as a good practice you should add a service layer between your Controller and Repo Class. Mark all the methods of Service class that do Database operations as `@Transactional`.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/ ... crud is transactional by default.